# How to show a box for comment reply with id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My reply only work in last/new comment. if i reply others comment its show a blank space only in text area.

Test case: If I REPLACE REPLY FORM AT THE END of wall.php page, apply css display:block to show it always, click a reply button for parent id and submit after write any text then it work but click to reply button cannot open to it's own reply form.

How to open my reply form with each comment if I replace it at end of page?

wall.php (current case: as above link which not save any textarea data of old comments)

```
script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function(){
    $("a.reply").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#parent_id").attr("value", id);
    });
  });
</script>

<script>
$('a.reply').livequery("click",function() {
   var ID = $(this).attr('id').replace('','');
   $("#reply_here-"+ID).slideToggle('slow');
   return false;
}); 
</script>
</head>


global $dbh;
$results = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM comments_lite WHERE qazi_id='$tutid' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
//find the number of comments
list($commentNum) = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments_lite WHERE qazi_id='$tutid'"));

echo'<div class="comments"><div id="updates"><div class="content"><comment>';

while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) 
{
$id = $rows['id'];
$qazi_id = $rows['qazi_id'];
$likes = $rows['likes'];
$username = $rows['username'];
$img = $rows['img'];
$description = $rows['description'];        
$url = $rows['url'];
$parent_id = $rows['parent_id'];
$date = $rows['date'];

    echo'<div class="comment">
        <div class="cdomment_cheder">';
        if ($url=="") {
        echo'<p class="name">'.$username.' Says:</p>'; }
        else  echo'<p class="name"><a href="userinfo.php?user='.$url.'" title="'.$username.'">'.$username.'</a> Says:</p>';
        echo'<span class="cdomment_time">'.$date.'</span><br/>
        <div class="avatarcnt">
        <img alt="" src="uploadprofile/'.$u_imgurl.'"/>
        </div></div></div>
        <div class="cdomment_text">';
        if ($description=="") {echo '';}
        else echo''.htmlentities($description).'<br>';
        echo '</div>';


//reply
echo'<div class="reply_box"><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="reply" id="'.$id.'">Reply</a></div>';

//Likes
echo'<div></div>'; 

// Only Reply 
$query = "SELECT * FROM comments_reply WHERE parent_id ='".$id."' ORDER BY id DESC";
$res = mysqli_query($dbh,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){   
$id = $row['id'];
$qazi_id = $row['qazi_id'];
$likes = $row['likes'];
$username = $row['username'];
$img = $row['img'];
$description = $row['description'];     
$url = $row['url'];
$parent_id = $row['parent_id'];
$date = $row['date'];

        echo' <div class="rcontent"><replycomment><ul>
        <div class="comment">
        <div class="cdomment_cheder">';
        if ($url=="") {
        echo'<p class="name">'.$username.' Says:</p>'; }
        else  echo'<p class="name"><a href="userinfo.php?user='.$url.'" title="'.$username.'">'.$username.'</a> Says:</p>';
        echo'<span class="cdomment_time">'.$date.'</span><br/>
        <div class="avatarcnt">
        <img alt="" src="uploadprofile/'.$u_imgurl.'"/>
        </div></div></div>
        <div class="cdomment_text">';
        if ($description=="") {echo '';}
        else echo''.htmlentities($description).'<br>';
        echo '</div>';

        </ul><replycomment></div>'; 

}   //reply close   
?>

// REPLY FORM
<div id="loader"></div><div class="reply_here" id="reply_here-<?php echo $rows['id'] ?>" style="display:none;">
    <form action="" method="post" id="repfrm">
      <fieldset id="cmntfs">
        <legend class="pyct">Your comment</legend>
        <input type="hidden" name="username" id="author" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="" />
        <div id="maintbox">
        <textarea name="replycom" rows="2" id="replycom"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" id="parent_id" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="tutid" id="tutid" value="<?php echo $tutid ?>" />
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="" id="submit" class="repfrm">Post Reply</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<?
}    //comment close

echo'</div><comment></div>';

//pagination
```

wall.php (tast case: this not open each reply form when form placed at the end of page)

```
script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
 $("a.reply").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
 $("#parent_id").attr("value", id);
 });
});
</script>

<script>
$('a.reply').livequery("click",function() {
 var ID = $(this).attr('id').replace('','');
  $("#reply_here-"+ID).slideToggle('slow');
  return false;
}); 
</script>
</head>


global $dbh;
$results = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM comments_lite WHERE qazi_id='$tutid' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
//find the number of comments
list($commentNum) = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments_lite WHERE qazi_id='$tutid'"));

echo'<div class="comments"><div id="updates"><div class="content"><comment>';

while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
$id = $rows['id'];
$qazi_id = $rows['qazi_id'];
$likes = $rows['likes'];
$username = $rows['username'];
$img = $rows['img'];
$description = $rows['description'];        
$url = $rows['url'];
$parent_id = $rows['parent_id'];
$date = $rows['date'];

    echo'<div class="comment">
        <div class="cdomment_cheder">';
        if ($url=="") {
        echo'<p class="name">'.$username.' Says:</p>'; }
        else  echo'<p class="name"><a href="userinfo.php?user='.$url.'" title="'.$username.'">'.$username.'</a> Says:</p>';
        echo'<span class="cdomment_time">'.$date.'</span><br/>
        <div class="avatarcnt">
        <img alt="" src="uploadprofile/'.$u_imgurl.'"/>
        </div></div></div>
        <div class="cdomment_text">';
        if ($description=="") {echo '';}
        else echo''.htmlentities($description).'<br>';
        echo '</div>';


//reply
echo'<div class="reply_box"><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="reply" id="'.$id.'">Reply</a></div>';

//Likes
echo'<div></div>'; 

// Only Reply 
$query = "SELECT * FROM comments_reply WHERE parent_id ='".$id."' ORDER BY id DESC";
$res = mysqli_query($dbh,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){   
$id = $row['id'];
$qazi_id = $row['qazi_id'];
$likes = $row['likes'];
$username = $row['username'];
$img = $row['img'];
$description = $row['description'];     
$url = $row['url'];
$parent_id = $row['parent_id'];
$date = $row['date'];

        echo' <div class="rcontent"><replycomment><ul>
        <div class="comment">
        <div class="cdomment_cheder">';
        if ($url=="") {
        echo'<p class="name">'.$username.' Says:</p>'; }
        else  echo'<p class="name"><a href="userinfo.php?user='.$url.'" title="'.$username.'">'.$username.'</a> Says:</p>';
        echo'<span class="cdomment_time">'.$date.'</span><br/>
        <div class="avatarcnt">
        <img alt="" src="uploadprofile/'.$u_imgurl.'"/>
        </div></div></div>
        <div class="cdomment_text">';
        if ($description=="") {echo '';}
        else echo''.htmlentities($description).'<br>';
        echo '</div>';

        </ul><replycomment></div>'; 

}   //reply close   
}    //comment close
?>

// REPLY FORM
<div id="loader"></div><div class="reply_here" id="reply_here-<?php echo $rows['id'] ?>" style="display:block;">
    <form action="" method="post" id="repfrm">
      <fieldset id="cmntfs">
        <legend class="pyct">Your comment</legend>
        <input type="hidden" name="username" id="author" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="" />
        <div id="maintbox">
        <textarea name="replycom" rows="2" id="replycom"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" id="parent_id" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="tutid" id="tutid" value="<?php echo $tutid ?>" />
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="" id="submit" class="repfrm">Post Reply</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<?
echo'</div><comment></div>';

//pagination
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by adding a javasrcipt which dynamically add text on its value. Thank u Sir Useless Intern also to comment me here.

```
$(".replycom").bind("keyup", function() {
$(".replycom").text($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem is that you have multiple reply text areas but only one of them works. I like to start with the simplest errors and I say that is because you only have ONE id for the textarea in the reply form.

HTML will pull the first id/name it seems and discard the rest if they share the same name and if the first one is null then that's what is posted.

So at some point you need to iterate the 'replycom' name/id **THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE**:

```
 $replyNumber = 0;

...


<textarea name="replycom$replyNumber" rows="2" id="replycom$replyNumber"></textarea>
```

**EDIT**
I just remembered that you can define a variable as an array in HTMl

```
<textarea name="replycom[]" rows="2" id="replycom"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you Useless Intem, without u no one can help or guideline me. 5 days long i was trying to solved it. But I cannot understand your solution please. how to do it? give me something more sir.

Comment: Sir my every form slidedown with its own id, also save username and parent id etc. but cannot save only text of textarea.

Comment: Yes it has an id but its the same id, at least on  http://bdshowbiz.com/loginfinal/demo.php. I checked with firebug.

Comment: sir please see it now (not working) bdshowbiz.com/loginfinal/demo.php